# Signed SSL Certificates for server without port 80/443

Tags: ssl

I am stuck with a security issue.

I registered my domain with amazon Route53, but the actual server is not hosted at Amazon at all. Instead it is hosted by a 3rd party, and only 2 ports are opened on this instance: port 22 (for SSH) and port 1337 (for websockets).

The application runs fine, but I need to enable HTTPS now for this server.

In the past I used the AWS loadbalancer to forward HTTPS to HTTP on a specific EC2 instance, and that works great, without having the need to actually create a certificate for the specific instance.

Unfortunately, I have the impression that I cannot use this approach now, because the server is hosted elsewhere, and the loadbalancer only works for AWS instances.

By contrast, I did configure a record to redirect the hostname to the IP address of the server, which works fine.

I decided to make the certificates myself. However, it appears that my self-signed certificates are blocked by chrome by default. So, instead I tried to use a CA. I tried this with LetsEncrypt, however it wasn't a success. The problem, is that LetsEncrypt wants to validate the hostname halfway through the installation, and it can only do this on port 80 it seems, which I do not have at my disposal.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why didn't you use DNS validation instead?

Comment: Thanks, I read about doing this with letsencrypt. It said to create a TXT record for my DNS. But in all honesty I didn't understand it. I was so naive to think they meant a txt file in the root of my webserver. But it all makes sense now. Just received my 2 pem files. Yihaa !

Comment: @MichaelHampton added some screenshots, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read that LetsEncrypt wanted me to create a `TXT` record. I was so foolish to think they wanted me to create a TXT file in the root of my public folder.
All thanks to Michael Hampton really, who pointed me in the right direction with 2 simple words: "DNS Validation"

[image: picture]

The result:

[image]

## EDIT:

The following years I discovered how hard it was to maintain these certificates, because they relied on manual tasks (i.e. adding TXT records). And I had to write my own set of scripts to update those TXT records, which wasn't easy.

Comment: PS: I did have to try this process 3 times before it worked. Even though I could see the TXT records with my test tools straightaway on all 3 attempts, I guess that letsencrypt couldn't see them yet. Only the 3rd time they could find them.

Comment: Let's Encrypt DNS challenge **does not** reqire any periodic manual tasks. Update of TXT records (or any other) could be automated. Each major DNS hoster provides some API for that and certbot has plugins for many of them; also there is generic DNS update protocol described in RFC2136 based on TSIG which is supported on all modern serious origin servers (BIND and PowerDNS I tested by myself) and there is also a ready made plugin for that. People at Let's Encrypt assume you'll end up using this automation for completing DNS challenges.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov  my decision for using TXT records, was the lack of a webserver. Most renewal plugins/scripts do expect some kind of webserver to be in place to post a secret to verify the identity. AWS did provide me with an API to update their TXT records, and the easiest solution that I found was to wrap the CLI tools in a Node.js application. It works, but technically, it's ugly. It would have been cool if Let's encrypt had an API for this or something.

Comment: No. Just no. DNS plugins expect either DNS hoster API or DNS RFC2136-compliant updates, which is done by special DNS query. Nothing here expects a web server on your side, nor requires additional scripting. For AWS there is a dedicated plugin for Route53 API. You've just missed the relevant documentation: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/dns-providers-who-easily-integrate-with-lets-encrypt-dns-validation/86438 https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?highlight=dns#dns-plugins

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov yes, totally overlooked that. Nice catch. Keeping this for future reference: https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/